# The illusion has dropped / is over?

Tags: idioms

I'm looking for an idiom that means the illusion is over or the illusion has dropped. Ironically, I wonder if either of these phrases is the idiom I'm looking for. The reason I doubt this is that there aren't a lot of google hits for these phrases. I can't seem to find it in an idioms dictionary. Any thoughts?

To clarify, what I would like to express by the idiom is, the illusion that we were under is now gone.

Comment: The illusion is figurative right?

Comment: Right. Like, an illusion between two people. "The illusion has dropped. I see you are not my friend." Bad example, but I hope it makes the point.

Comment: Illusions can _fade_, or _fade out_, or with knowledge be _lost_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fog](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fog) has lifted

> Something that confuses or obscures.
>
> A state of confusion and bewilderment.

**To [lift](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lift) the fog** means to dissipate or clear something that has been causing bewilderment or confusion.

Also, try [jig is up](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_jig_is_up). It means

> Your trick or game is finished, has been exposed, we're onto you now.
>
> Being discovered or scheme has ended.

Example - Your jig is up, I know you aren't my friend.

Comment: That's great! That may be it. I'm still curious if there are other expressions, perhaps including the word "illusion".

Comment: @ktm5124 I'm looking an thinking. Will edit in few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Illusions can be *seen through* or *pierced*. This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=see%20through%20the%20illusion%2Cpierce%20the%20illusion%2Cillusion%20is%20over&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csee%20through%20the%20illusion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpierce%20the%20illusion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cillusion%20is%20over%3B%2Cc0) indicates that *seen through* is significantly more popular than *pierce*. Your phrase *the illusion is over* sits in between these two.

Interestingly, based on the results in the ngram, *seeing through* illusions tends to be used to refer to bypassing *reality* to see something else. *Piercing* illusions tends to be more idiomatic the other way around. However, both constructs are used to refer to the viewing of something more fundamental than the illusion.

Here is an example:

> If we are still feeling resentment, anger, condemnation, and blame, we have one again not pierced the illusion and seen the truth. In the illusion we not only believe the other is the cause of our unhappiness (the special hate relationship) but we also expect the other to be more perfect, rather than "perfectly imperfect." [- Robert Roskind, *In the Spirit of Marriage: Creating and sustaining Loving Relationships](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=5yjl6cvNfSIC&pg=PA165&dq=%22pierced%20the%20illusion%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxh5T29M7MAhVCGaYKHXXCDBUQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22pierced%20the%20illusion%22&f=false)

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. I never knew about those ngrams. Also, great example.